# Delete an image after it has been seen by a visitor

Tags: php, unlink

I want to show my visitors the images in a folder and after then have seen it, I want all those files deleted!

This is what I tried, but It won't work. I think it's because PHP is generating a html file which tells the browser it must first get an image from a different place but the html file was already removed.

```
<?php
    foreach (glob("files/*.*") as $prevpic) {
        echo '<img src="' . $prevpic . '" />';
    }
    foreach (glob("files/*.*") as $file) {
        unlink($file);
    }
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "files/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
?>
```

Comment: `Delete an image after seen by visitor`? How do you track who has viewed that image? Even in your testing those image files will be deleted.

Comment: First person sees the image, but the 2nd, 3rd... etc. won't. Hm...

Comment: And that first person could be OP himself or a search bot...

Comment: @anubhava Indeed, and probably as "herself" ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- lol :) Yes, I should have been more gender sensitive.

Comment: @anubhava It's an honest mistake ;-) rare to find a female coder nowadays

Comment: I'm always weary of the dreaded `unlink` command. Think I'll skip and delete files via FTP, thank you.

Comment: Well this will happen if someone uploads an image but before the image will be moved the image before is shown and deleted. This is just a part of the full thing.

Comment: @user2741021 If the image that is uploaded is going to be kept, why delete it in the first place? I mean, by having them upload the image just for it to be deleted? Why don't you just `echo` the image itself after it is uploaded, then set a header redirect? There's obviously something I am not getting/grasping here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I want the uploader to see the previously uploaded image. The idea is that you upload an image to see an image and the next uploader will see your image.

Comment: @user2741021 Ok I understand. Now the problem with that is, once "one" person goes through the process, the next one won't. Meaning, whatever you try and risks to be successfull, will only work for one person. I suggest you go about this in another way. I do get what you mean though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like so ...

```
<?php

    foreach (glob("files/*.*") as $file) {
        echo '<img src="data:image/' . pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)) . '" />';
        unlink($file);
    }

?>
```

... which is basically writing the image data into the html, and then discarding the image.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this by simply managing your images through a download script (php).
You track sessions and simply don't display the images requested, but fail gracefully with a response, or let your app handle it via session based tracking.

That way no images are deleted 'onview'.